# AWS RDS MYSQL Write Operation Counts Per Second

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, mariadb, amazon-rds

I'm making a mysql table and coding an API to receive and storing data for 1000 plus devices every second. Each device push more than 100 datapoints to this PHP server. I'm testing for 360 devices with 10 datapoints each, it went well with 3600 write counts per second, thats understandable. However, I noticed that the write operation counts per second increase with the number of devices. I'm trying to google the saturated point for number of write count per second but couldnt find any. Is there any maximum of write count per second? How is the system performance when the number of write count is reaching 100 thousand per second. Is anyone expert on mysql database please advice me, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You *might* be able to find a benchmark to that shows some high number in a *very limited* test case.  But there are too many factors that impact 'writes per second':

- Spinning drive vs SSD, plus brand, etc
- RAID
- Batched insert / LOAD DATA / single-row inserts / MyISAM
- Number of indexes
- BEGIN...COMMIT / autocommit
- Concurrency -- both of multiple writes, and also of simultaneous reads
- Settings: innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit, sync_binlog, etc
- Version (5.6 made some improvements; 5.7 made more; MariaDB has some of those improvements, plus others)
- Schema
- Client and Server vying for resources
- etc.

I have heard of a benchmark showing a million "transactions" per second in 5.7.

But, to get 100K is quite a challenge.  Here's what I recommend:

- SSD (probably exists in AWS; get the max IOPs)
- RAID striping (parity hurts some, but probably worth having)
- MyISAM, because of table locking, *may* not be a good idea if you use multiple-threaded inserting.  (I am assuming InnoDB in the rest of this discussion.)
- What will you be doing with the data?  If you do not need *SQL* to look at individual values, store the 100 values in a JSON string and compress it into a BLOB.  Now you are down to a leisurely 1000 writes/second.
- FusionIO SSDs might do the compression for you.  I don't like InnoDB's automatic compression.  Doing it in the Client offloads the Server.
- Indexes:  Once you have a huge amount of data, the random updates of the indexes will kill you.  Design the `PRIMARY KEY` so that the inserts can be "at the end of the table".
- Insert 100-10K rows per batch -- less than that leads to overhead costs; more than that leads to inefficiencies in overrunning the undo log, etc.
- `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2`, `sync_binlog` may not matter because of the batching.
- 5.7, possibly MariaDB 10.1
- If necessary, move the Client(s) to separate servers.

As for how to collect lots of data fast, possibly with multiple threads, read my ["High speed ingestion"](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table) blog.  It talks about ping-ponging a pair of tables -- one for receiving data, the other for processing (normalizing, compressing, summarizing) and shoveling into the Fact table.

Another issue...  You are trying to push a few MB into a table every second; that adds up to nearly a terabyte per day.  How long will you keep the data?  How much disk space do you have?  If you will be deleting 'old' data, then `PARTITION BY RANGE` is a must.  My [Partitioning blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint) goes into detail on how to do the `DROP PARTITION` and `REORGANIZE PARTITION` to do the deletes very cheaply.

That leads to another suggestion -- process the data, but don't save it.  OK, maybe you need an hour's data to process.  In this case all the above discussion still applies (except for `INDEX` restrictions).  And my High speed ingestion is probably still worth doing.  And you could ping-pong once an hour.  One hour might be 10GB -- enough to keep in RAM, hence avoiding the I/O bottleneck.

Comment: Thank you very much guys. This answer helped me tons...I'm trying my best to use the relational database to store the historian data because there is benefit to it, if I stitch all data to blob then it's no different to use no sql isnt it? I want to use sql function like max min fulltext search etc, that's really help for get data query...

Answer (score 1):

Also consider the underlying EC2 instance size of your provisioned RDS.